# French word list with genders

Tags: genre, ressources, lexique

I have been looking for a list of French *nouns* with corresponding gender for a machine learning experiment. So far I've only found lists of words without gender, or small lists including gender mostly embedded in html pages. Could anyone point me to a comprehensive (10000+), free, downloadable word list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aller sur *[Dicollecte](http://www.dicollecte.org/download.php?prj=fr)*

Cliquer sur *Lexique [5.2]* et télécharger.

Après décompression, votre bonheur se trouve dans le fichier *lexique-dicollecte-fr-v5.2.txt*

... bienvenue en francophonie !

Comment: Merci bien à tous! Interestingly, now with two lists as answers we can compare a bit and I noted that the following words are feminine in the Dicollecte list and masculine in the Lexique list: "auto-tamponneuse", "belon", "binaire", "borée", "corpuscule", "flaveur", "haut-de-chausse", "idée-force", "marine", "myriophylle", "penny", "raideur", "sparte", "tire-fesse", "zénana"

Comment: Same thing for the plurals: "balanes", "belons", "binaires", "boxes", "corpuscules", "délices", "fixe-chaussettes", "hydromètres", "ides", "lombes", "marines", "orgues", "ranches", "tétragones"

Comment: Le Robert indique *Belon* féminin (c'est le nom d'une huître plate et arrondie), parfois masculin ; *binaire* est un adjectif épicène ; *borée* n'est pas référencée mais peut être un adjectif au féminin, relatif au *bore* ; *corpuscule, haut-de-chausse, sparte, penny, zénana* sont masculins

Comment: *orgue, délice, amour* sont masculins au singulier, et féminin au pluriel. Les autres sont à vérifier avec *http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/* .

Comment: Le pluriel d’« orgues » est même féminin lorsqu’il désigne tout ou partie d’un seul instrument (« les grandes orgues ») et masculin lorsqu’il en désigne plusieurs (les plus beaux orgues de  la ville).

Comment: There is no way 'auto-tamponneuse' can be masculine since '-euse' is really a feminine suffixe, opposed to '-eur' for masculine. 'Tire-fesses' is masculine. 'Raideur' is a feminine word for 'stiffness', but we have the masculine word 'raideur' which comes from the English 'raider'.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps  auto[mobile] est féminin, son adjectif aussi -- une tire est une voiture en argot, mais surtout, on l'associe à tire-bouchons qui est masculin.

Answer (score 4):

I'll add [Lexique](http://www.lexique.org/) to the list. You can [download it](http://www.lexique.org/telLexique.php) in Excel format, and use the Find feature to search for words when you have the document open.

The first 6 columns are the most interesting to French learners (and non-linguists), so you may consider deleting the other columns. There are also [other resources](http://www.lexique.org/telAutresBases.php) available from the same group.

Comment: Pour l'ouvrir sous LibreOffice ou sous OpenOffice, il faut d'abord transformer les tabulations en `;` et changer le *.txt* en *.csv*

Comment: Merci beaucoups! Interestingly, now with two lists we can compare a bit and I noted that the following words are masculine in the Dicollecte list and feminine in the Lexique list: "acerbité", "aérobic", "alexithymie", "baston", "bute", "calcite", "chamane", "conteste", "ecstasy", "intifada", "job", "liche", "loco", "pole", "robinsonnade", "rocket", "super", "syzygie", "tome", "unetelle".

Comment: Same thing for the plurals: "aérobics", "bastons", "chamanes", "faînes", "grands-oncles", "iles", "jobs", "jupes-culottes", "kilotonnes", "locos", "rockets", 
"santiags", "supers", "syzygies", "tapas", "tomes"

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Interesting... I'll have to look into that when my semester is over. If you're interested, the [TLF](http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/tlfiv4/showps.exe?p=combi.htm;java=no) is a good source to compare against.

Comment: I noticed quite a few of the differences concern loan words, so I can imagine that gender will not be well defined there. There's still work for the Académie française to do.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Ah yeah, if there are differences, for your algorithms it might be safe to assume masculine/singular. If you want, you can try to guess by the morphology of the word, but that's more linguistic work and I don't know if you'd be interested in doing that.

Comment: Well, the above are only a small minority. The two lists combined give me 92996 nouns (f/m; p/s). A few misclassifications (if they are that) won't mind.